# Data not getting added to database MongoDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, bcrypt

I was trying to get the user info linked with the database but data is not being updated in my database.
I feel like my data is not being transferred from the API to database.

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const Register = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch("api/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: name,
        email: email,
        password: password,
      }),
    });
  };
  return (
    <div className="h-screen grid content-center justify-items-center">
      <div className="w-1/4  bg-accent2 text-black px-6 pb-5 pt-10 border-none rounded-lg ">
        <h1 className="text-white font-bold text-center text-2xl mb-10 ">
          Create your account
        </h1>
        <form className="flex flex-col " onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            onChange={(e) => {
              setName(e.target.value);
            }}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Name"
            className="p-3 rounded-t-md border-2  border-t-accent border-r-accent border-l-accent"
          />
          <input
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEmail(e.target.value);
            }}
            type="text"
            placeholder="Email"
            className="p-3 border-2  border-r-accent border-l-accent"
          />
          <input
            onChange={(e) => {
              setPassword(e.target.value);
            }}
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            className="p-3 mb-10 rounded-b-md border-2  border-b-accent border-r-accent border-l-accent"
          />
          <div className="flex justify-between text-white mb-5 ">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className=" bg-accent p-2 border-2 border-accent   rounded-full w-1/4 font-semibold transition btnHover"
            >
              Sign Up
            </button>
            <a href="/" className="text-sm ">
              Already have an account?{" "}
              <span className="text-accent">Log In</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

This is the API route:

```
import connectMongoDb from "@/lib/mongoDb";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import User from "@/models/user";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body.json();
    let hashPassword = "";
    bcrypt.hash(password, 10, function (err, hash) {
      hashPassword = hash;
      console.log(err);
    });
    await connectMongoDb();
    await User.create({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: hashPassword,
    });
    return NextResponse.json({ massage: "User regsitered." }, { status: 201 });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { message: "An error occured while registering the user." },
      { stauts: 500 }
    );
  }
}
```

This is the MongoDB schema:

```
import mongoose, { Schema, models } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

const User = models.User || mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
export default User;
```

Hope that I would get a quick fix?

I am also getting the request status as 200 don't know why this is happening hope to get a solution.

Answer (score -1):

There are several issues in your code:

Your usage of `bcrypt` for password hashing is asynchronous, but you're not waiting for the hash to be generated before creating the user. This can result in an empty or incorrect `hashPassword` being saved. Use await with bcrypt.hash to ensure you get the hashed password before proceeding.

```
let hashPassword = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  bcrypt.hash(password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) reject(err);
    resolve(hash);
  });
});
```

Also, The `status` in your catch block is misspelled as "stauts". Correct this one also for future errors.

You are using `NextResponse.json` incorrectly. The second argument is not for setting the status. Change your response format to set the status correctly

```
return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: "User registered." }), { status: 201 });
```

Your client-side code does not handle the response from the API. This is why you always see a status of 200, as unhandled errors in the API might not propagate as expected. Add response handling to check for errors or successful registration.

```
const response = await fetch("api/register", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: name,
    email: email,
    password: password,
  }),
});
const data = await response.json();
if (response.status !== 201) {
  console.error('Registration failed:', data.message);
} else {
  console.log('Registration successful:', data.message);
}
```

Ensure that you check both your client and server-side consoles for any errors. Verify that your MongoDB connection is established correctly. Make sure the endpoint in your client-side fetch matches the actual API route.